# Retrieve keys from hash-table, sorted by the values, efficiently

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I'm using Emacs Lisp, but have the `cl` package loaded, for *some* common lisp features.

I have a hash table containing up to 50K entries, with integer keys mapped to triplets, something like this (but in actual lisp):

```
{
  8   => '(9  300 12)
  27  => '(5  125 9)
  100 => '(10 242 14)
}
```

The second value in the triplet is a score that has been calculated during a complex algorithm that built the hash-table. I need to collect a regular lisp list with all of the keys from the hash, ordered by the score (i.e. all keys ordered by the cadr of the value).

So for the above, I need this list:

```
'(27 100 8)
```

I'm currently doing this with two phases, which feels less efficient than it needs to be.

Is there a good way to do this?

My current solution uses `maphash` to collect the keys and the values into two new lists, then does a `sort` in the normal way, referring to the list of scores in the predicate. It feels like I could be combining the collection and the sorting together, however.

EDIT | I'm also not attached to using hash-table, though I do need constant access time for the integer keys, which are not linearly spaced.

EDIT 2| It looks like implementing a binary tree sort could work, where the labels in the tree are the scores and the values are the keys... this way I'm doing the sort as I map over the hash.

*... Continues reading wikipedia page on sorting algorithms*

Comment: Are you programming in Elisp or Common Lisp?

Comment: I'm using elisp, but I do have the cl (common lisp) package loaded, for some (very) basic common lisp compatibility.

Comment: Note that `cl` is deprecated; it gives an illusion of CL compatibility but there are some subtle bugs and incompatibilities. Beware!

Comment: EmacsWiki has an example: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElispCookbook#toc45

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically, you solution is correct: you need to collect the keys into a list:

```
(defun hash-table-keys (hash-table)
  (let ((keys ()))
    (maphash (lambda (k v) (push k keys)) hash-table)
    keys))
```

and then sort the list:

```
(sort (hash-table-keys hash-table)
      (lambda (k1 k2)
        (< (second (gethash k1 hash-table))
           (second (gethash k2 hash-table)))))
```

Combining key collection with sorting is possible: you need to collect the keys into a tree and then "flatten" the tree. However, this will only matter if you are dealing with really huge tables. Also, since Emacs Lisp compiles to bytecodes, you might find that using the `sort` built-in is still faster than using a tree. Consider also the development cost - you will need to write code whose value will be mostly educational.

Delving deeper, collecting the keys allocates the list of keys (which you will certainly need anyway for the result) and `sort` operates "in-place", so the "simple way" is about as good as it gets.

The "tree" way will allocate the tree (the same memory footprint as the required list of keys) and populating and flattening it will be the same `O(n*log(n))` process as the "collect+sort" way. However, keeping the tree balanced, and then flattening it "in-place" (i.e., without allocating a new list) is not a simple exercise.

The bottom line is: [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Comment: Well that's definitely simpler than what I was doing and blindingly obvious now that I see it in code (clearly I need sleep), though I do have to wonder if I can avoid the initial 50K operations collecting the keys and combine the sort with the collection of those keys.

Comment: Thanks for the note in your edit about the tree sort. I've done binary trees in lisp before, just never for the purpose of sorting. I'll give it a shot and compare the results with just using sort. You're right that the trade-off in theoretical complexity may be outweighed by one being done in C and the other in the interpreted language.

Comment: The is no win even theoretically. At most, you will win `n` operations of key collection, but it is dwarfed by the total `n*log(n)` cost. You will spend hours writing and debugging code for no performance gain. This might be a valuable educational exercise, though.